# What is process lsd on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, daemons

There is a process running on my iOS device (7.1.2) called 'lsd'. The file is in /usr/libexec/lsd. What is it and what does it do?

**Device info:**

iPad 2 (7.2.1)

Jailbroken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lsd in iOS is the LaunchServiceDaemon.
It provides according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html)

> support for launching apps and matching document types to apps. As a result, the keys recognized by Launch Services allow you to specify the desired execution environment for your bundled code.

Despite the name nothing to worry about.